# What can I deduce from a matrix by its Jordan Canonical Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I solved an interesting, but troubling, problem stated as follows:

> If $f(x) = (x-2)^3(x+7)^2 $ is the characteristic polynomial and $p(x) = (x-2)^2(x+7)$ is the minimal polynomial for a $5$x$5$ complex matrix $A$, what is the Jordan Form of $A$?

I found the Jordan form to be:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -7 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -7 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Using a combination of Primary Decomposition Theorem, Cyclic Decomposition Theorem, and Caley Hamilton Theorem.

However, my concern is how I would *use* such a matrix. I don't know what basis I'm using to get this form, nor do I have handy the form of $A$. I believe I could extract some basic quantities like the rank and nullity of $A$ from here, but finding the image and kernel would be effectively useless without being able to convert the vectors to and from standard coordinates as far as I can tell.

I suppose my questions are:

> What kind of information is the Jordan Form providing me with here?
>
> Can I, without first finding $A$, extract the basis that I am using (up to ordering) to represent $A$ in this Jordan form?

Answer (score 1):

You can **easily** extract the following information about a matrix in JCF:

Its rank, its eigenvalues and their algebraic and geometric multiplicites,  its determinant, its trace ...

I think that's a lot of info that you cannot get **easily** from a matrix not in JCF.

Now, basis with eigenvectors and/or generalized eigenvectors you cannot get it, as far as I can see, only from the JCF. In particular, when the matrix is not diagonalizable, as in your example, you'll have generalized eigenvectors (which *are not* eigenvectors).

BTW, I think most of the usual representations of JCF use the **upper** triangular form, which menas that $\;1\;$ you put there in entry 2-1 would rather go in entry 1-2.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It seems to me that the only properties I'm getting that weren't already given by the characteristic polynomial/minimal polynomial are the rank and nullity.
Also, I have noticed that is the typical convention for JCF, but the book I am using (Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze) gives an alternative treatment with the lower triangular form, which arises naturally from how they define Cyclic Decomposition Theorem (and in turn, RCF).

Comment: @infinitylord The nullity is the exponent of $x$ in the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @amd: What do you mean by the exponent of $x$? The degree of the characteristic polynomial is the dimension of $V$, so I presume that's not what you mean. Do you mean that if $f(x) = x^k g(x)$ where $g$ is some polynomial with a non-zero constant term, then $k = \text{nullity}(A)$?

Comment: Yes, the latter.